# Is there a utility method for creating a list with specified size and contents?

Tags: java, apache-commons, utility, utility-method

```
public static <T> List<T> repeat(T contents, int length) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        list.add(contents);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is a utility method in our proprietary commons libraries. It's useful for creating lists. For example, I might want a list of 68 question marks for generating a large SQL query. This lets you do that in one line of code, instead of four lines of code.

Is there a utility class somewhere in java/apache-commons which already does this? I browsed ListUtils, CollectionUtils, Arrays, Collections, pretty much everything I could think of but I can't find it anywhere. I don't like keeping generic utility methods in my code, if possible, since they're usually redundant with apache libraries.

Comment: Will Arrays.fill work for you ? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Arrays.fill would be a little clumsy here, it fits a slightly different role.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Collections` utility class will help you:

```
list = Collections.nCopies(length,contents);
```

or if you want a mutable list:

```
list = new ArrayList<T>(Collections.nCopies(length,contents));
           // or whatever List implementation you want.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

Google Guava has the following:

```
newArrayListWithExpectedSize(int estimatedSize)
```

and:

```
newArrayList(E... elements)
```

but you can't do both, maybe submit a patch if it's going to be useful.  More info here:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html

Comment: I'm not sure how different that is, in context, from using Arrays.asList(). The Collections.nCopies() method mentioned above is a perfect fit, so I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`java.util.Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) ?

You can just pass in the contents as a [var-arg](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
List<String> planets = Arrays.asList( "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars" );
```

Mind you, you can pass in an array as well:

```
String[] ps = new String[]{ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars" };
List<String> planets = Arrays.asList( ps );
```

but it is "backed" by the array in that changing the contents of the array will be reflected in the list:

```
String[] ps = new String[]{ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars" };
List<String> planets = Arrays.asList( ps );
ps[3] = "Terra";
assert planets.get(3).equals( "Terra" );
```